# Web Scraping over dynamic content

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would appreciate with helping me scrape results from the following link: 
[sample link](https://www.booking.com/hotel/us/apartment-eldridge.en-gb.html?aid=304142;label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNYBGgxiAEBmAEuwgEDYWJuyAEO2AEB6AEB-AELkgIBeagCBA;sid=7860ef0f052cdf7b66e03d38cc2ff7b4;dest_id=20088325;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=1;group_children=0;hapos=13;hpos=13;nflt=class%3D1%3B;no_rooms=1;req_adults=1;req_children=0;room1=A;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=class_and_price;srepoch=1572010918;srpvid=72b46053510a0197;type=total;ucfs=1&#tab-reviews)

I'm using Python 3.7, BeautifulSoup 4, and Selenium.

I have coded a program to extract features of user reviews for hotels such as reviewer name, review date, reviewer score, reviewer country, staying date, review title as well as the review itself (in this case, the review is separated into a positive and negative section).
I use BeautifulSoup 4 to extract the text from the HTML tags, relying on Selenium to click on the 'cookie notification' button as well as loop through the page results.

While I am successfully looping through the page results, I am not extracting the content retrieved after the first page onwards. Each N pages retrieves the same content from the first results page, I'm betting this might be because the contents are loaded via JQuery. At this point, I'm not sure what the behavior is or what I need to look for in the page source or how to go about finding a solution.

Any hints or advice would be highly appreciated!

Crude snippet of my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/admin/Desktop/chrome_driver/chromedriver')

#initiate driver-browser via Selenium - with original url
driver.get('link1')

def acceptCookies():
    time.sleep(3)
    element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='cookie-warning-v2__banner-cta bui-button bui-button--wide bui-button--secondary close_warning']")
    if element != None:
        element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='cookie-warning-v2__banner-cta bui-button bui-button--wide bui-button--secondary close_warning']")
        element[0].click()

def getData(count, soup):
    try:
        for line in soup.find_all('li', class_='review_item'): 
            count += 1
            review={}
            review["review_metadata"]={}
            review["review_metadata"]["review_date"] = line.find('p', class_='review_item_date').text.strip()
            if line.find('p', class_='review_staydate') != None:
                review["review_metadata"]["review_staydate"] = line.find('p', class_='review_staydate').text.strip()
            review["review_metadata"]["reviewer_name"] = line.find('p', class_='reviewer_name').text.strip()
            print(review["review_metadata"]["reviewer_name"])
            review["review_metadata"]["reviewer_country"] = line.find('span', class_='reviewer_country').text.strip()
            review["review_metadata"]["reviewer_score"] = line.find('span', class_='review-score-badge').text.strip()
            if line.find('p', class_='review_pos') != None:
                review["review_metadata"]["review_pos"] = line.find('p', class_='review_pos').text.strip()
            if line.find('p', class_='review_neg') != None:
                review["review_metadata"]["review_neg"] = line.find('p', class_='review_neg').text.strip()
            scoreword = line.find('span', class_='review_item_header_scoreword')
            if scoreword != None :
                review["review_metadata"]["review_header"] = scoreword.text.strip()
            else:
                review["review_metadata"]["review_header"] = ""  
            hotel_reviews[count] = review
        return hotel_reviews
    except Exception as e:
        return print('the error is', e)

# Finds max-range of pagination (number of result pages retrieved)
def find_max_pages():
    max_pages = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='bui-pagination__list']//div//span")
    max_pages = max_pages[-1].text
    max_pages = max_pages.split()
    max_pages = int(max_pages[1])

    return max_pages


hotel_reviews= {}

count = 0
review_page = {}
hotel_reviews_2 = []

# Accept on Cookie-Notification
acceptCookies()
# Find Max Pages
max_pages = find_max_pages()
# Find every pagination link in order to loop through each review page carousel
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='bui-pagination__link']")
for item in range(max_pages-1):
    review_page = getData(count, soup)
    hotel_reviews_2.extend(review_page)
    time.sleep(2)
    element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='bui-pagination__link']")
    element[item].click()
    driver.get(url=driver.current_url)
    print(driver.page_source)
    print(driver.current_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
```

Comment: Did you tried adding a wait time ? After clicking, dynamic loading will take time.

Comment: @VishalKharde - in my script i've used a `time.sleep(2)`, so two second wait, but I wasn't sure where to place the wait time. I assume that after the `driver.get(driver.page_source)` command. Wdyt? Possibly two seconds is insufficient, however, testing the script line by line within `Jupyter Notebook`, I wait for a much longer period but yet the contents are not returned. Thing I am stuck on is that the url does not change (as its a tab) just the contents that opened in the side window that opens once the review button is clicked.

Comment: try placing it after element[item].click(). Experiment with different sleep time values

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference. What is the current method of grabbing the contents of the `tab-reviews` window-pane? `driver.current_url` , `driver.page_source` or something else? As there is no new url generated each I paginate, i'm not sure what is required to grab the latest contents.

Comment: I think I see the problem. Having looked at the sample link you provided, I see that `review_item` elements are only there to represent some recent reviews. The actual reviews on the sidebar are `review_list_new_item_block`s! Their format is a bit peskier but definitely workable.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The problem is not about waiting for elements to be loaded. The webpage simply does not have any more elements of class `review_item`. The `getData()` method needs to be updated to extract information from the proper elements, which are of class `review_list_new_item_block`.

Old answer:

I assume that once you click for a new results page, some elements on the page are removed while some others are added. You can just wait until a particular element goes stale using [WebDriverWait](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html?highlight=webdriverwait#selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(EC.staleness_of(element_of_interest));
```

If this is not applicable, maybe another condition is. It might be useful to check all predefined [conditions](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html).

Comment: Aribal - that is current, in that an inner table in the window-pane refreshes with new results while the older results are not visible any longer while scrolling throw the pagination feature. Would I need to use a 'wait' mechanism even if I manually try to `find` the tag elements? I'm running line after line of the script through PyCharm to test my code therefore the issue of contents not loading before the code is run is not applicable I believe. Perhaps the tag changes from the first page onwards and that is the issue. Really ensure to where the issue lies.